# JsonSerializer.Deserialize Many Time Use

Tags: c#, json, linq, serialization, json-deserialization

I have this code

```
        IssueRequest issueRequest = new IssueRequest
        {
            hotelCode = model.Criteria.Code,
            rooms = model.BookingOption.Rooms.Select(a => new RequestIssue
            {
                code = JsonSerializer.Deserialize<MyBag>(a.HotelRoom.myBag).code,
                contractCode = JsonSerializer.Deserialize<MyBag>(a.HotelRoom.myBag).contractCode,
                mealPlanCode = a.HotelRoom.MealPlan.Code,
                MyData = new Rooms
                {
                    RoomCode = JsonSerializer.Deserialize<MyBag>(a.Room.myBag).code,
                }
            }).ToArray()
        };
```

I use three times to   `JsonSerializer.Deserialize`
do you have idea for get better this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [statement lambda](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/statements-expressions-operators/lambda-expressions#statement-lambdas):

```
rooms = model.BookingOption.Rooms.Select(a => 
    {
        var deserialized = JsonSerializer.Deserialize<MyBag>(a.HotelRoom.myBag);
        return new RequestIssue
            {
                code = deserialized.code,
                contractCode = deserialized.contractCode,
                mealPlanCode = a.HotelRoom.MealPlan.Code,
                MyData = new Rooms
                {
                    RoomCode = JsonSerializer.Deserialize<MyBag>(a.Room.myBag).code,
                }
            };
     })
     .ToArray()
```

Comment: for ``RoomCode`` is ``a.Room`` not ``a.HotelRoom`` ;)

Comment: @PatrickBeynio, no, OP is not, OP is using simple [expression lambda](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/statements-expressions-operators/lambda-expressions#expression-lambdas) with `new` expression in it.

Comment: yea, just noticed :) but he could have still placed the variable outside the lambda, so just above his code. but the question makes more sense to me now

Comment: NP, glad it hepled!